# Python Image Library and KeyError: 'JPG'

Tags: python, macos, jpeg, python-imaging-library

This works:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw

def create_image_file(name='test.jpeg', ext='jpeg', size=(500, 500), color=(5, 179, 200)):
    file_obj = open(name, 'w')
    image = Image.new("RGBA", size=size, color=color)
    usr_font = ImageFont.truetype(
        "/Users/myuser/ENV/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data/fonts/ttf/Vera.ttf", 59)
    d_usr = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
    d_usr = d_usr.text((105, 280), "Test Image", (0, 0, 0), font=usr_font)
    image.save(file_obj, ext)
    file_obj.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    f = create_image_file()
```

But if I change the arguments to:

```
def create_image_file(name='test.jpg', ext='jpg', ...)
```

An exception is raised:

```
File "/Users/myuser/project/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1681, in save
    save_handler = SAVE[format.upper()]
KeyError: 'JPG'
```

And I need to work with user uploaded images that have `.jpg` as the extension.  Is this a Mac specific problem?  Is there something I can do to add the format data to the Image lib?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The second argument of `save` is **not** the extension, it is the format argument as specified in [image file formats](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/image-file-formats.html?highlight=Image%20Types) and the format specifier for JPEG files is `JPEG`, not `JPG`.

If you want `PIL` to decide which format to save, you can ignore the second argument, such as:

```py
image.save(name)
```

Note that in this case you can only use a file name and not a file object.

See the [documentation of `.save()` method](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html?highlight=Image.save#PIL.Image.Image.save) for details:

> **format** – Optional format override. If omitted, the format to use is determined from the filename extension. If a file object was used instead of a filename, this parameter should always be used.

Alternatively, you can check the extension and decide the format manually. For example:

```py
def create_image_file(name='test.jpeg', ext='jpeg', size=(500, 500), color=(5, 179, 200)):
    format = 'JPEG' if ext.lower() == 'jpg' else ext.upper()
    # ...
    image.save(file_obj, format)
```